# Unable to parse HTTP response body in Node.js

Tags: node.js, parsing, request

I am making the following request using the node.js request library:

```
request({
            method: 'POST',
            uri: TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
            'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

            body: JSON.stringify({
                code: req.query.code,
                client_id: CLIENT_ID,
                client_secret: latestSecret.properties.value,
                redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI,
                grant_type: 'authorization_code'
            })
        }, function (error, response, body) {
                console.log(body);
                console.log(body.access_token);
           }
        });
```

When I console.log(body) I get what I expect:

```
{
  "access_token": "...",
  "expires_in": 3598,
  "scope": "openid",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

but when I try to console.log body.token_type (or body.scope or other) I get 'undefined.'

I am clearly missing something very simple.  Help?

Comment: Can you provide a way for us to reproduce the issue in what stackoverflow calls a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  If not, all people can really do here is make wild guesses because what you report sounds pretty odd which usually means there's something else going on that you aren't showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried JSON.parse(body) before accessing body.token_type?